# Merge two sets, list and tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, sorting

We are given two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$.
We consider that $S_1$ is implemented, using a sorted list, and $S_2$ is implemented, using a pre-order sorted tree.
I have to write a pseudocode, that implements the operation Merge() of the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. 
The time complexity of the algorithm should be $O(n_1+n_2)$, where $n_1$ is the number of elements of $S_1$ and $n_2$ is the number of elements of $S_2$.

That's what I have tried:

```
SetMerge(LNODE *S1, TNODE *S2)
      LNODE *p1=S1
      TNODE *p2=S2
      LNODE *S, slast, new
      while(p1 != NULL p2 != NULL)
           new=newcell(NODE)
           if(p2->data < p1->data)
                 new->data=p2->data
                 if(p2 != NULL)
                     p2=p2->LC
                 else
                     p2=p2->RC
           else
                 new->data=p1->data
                 p1=p1->next
      new->next=NULL
      if(S==NULL)
         S=new
         slast=new
      else
         slast->next=new
         slast=new
      while(p1 != NULL)
         new=newcell(NODE)
         new->data=p1->data
         new->next=NULL
         if(S==NULL)
            S=new
            slast=new
         else
            slast->next=new
            slast=new
```

Could you tell me if it is right or if I have done something wrong?

Comment: You have placed a bounty on this question stating the current answer is out-of-date.  In what way is it out-of-date?   If you could be more specific as to why you want a new answer, people may respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your code is far from perfect, or I am misunderstanding it. If I do understand your intentions, there are multiple places where it could be improved, to name some issues

- In the following code
  \begin{align}
    &\verb`if(p2 != NULL)`\\
    &\verb`    p2=p2->LC`\\
    &\verb`else`\\
    &\verb`    p2=p2->RC`
    \end{align}
  the else branch looks up `NULL->RC` which would cause an error.
- In the first loop you never set `new->next`.
- In general, either you need to use some additional data structure (like stack or list to remember tree pointers), more loops (to recreate the tree pointers) or recursion; otherwise you won't be able to access all the elements of the tree.

To approach this problem I suggest you should divide it into two parts: making the tree into a list and then merging two list. Some may call such solution suboptimal, but it is simple, natural, and its asymptotic are just as good (even if the constants are a bit worse). To give you a start, the following function appends at the front the contents of a tree `tree` to a list `tail` (I'm trying to write in similar style of pseudocode you use, sorry if I got it wrong):

```
tree_to_list(tree, tail) = 
  if (tree == NULL) return tail
  else
    middle = tree_to_list(tree->RC, tail)
    new_tail = tree_to_list(tree->LC, middle)
    head = newcell(NODE)
    head->data = tree->data
    head->next = new_tail
    return head
```

Now you only need to write a function that would merge two lists, one given and one obtained from `tree_to_list`.

On the other hand, if you would insist on doing this without some additional lists, you can make it using a function which takes a list, a tree and returns a pair (first element of a list, an element of the list that corresponds to the last element of the tree). If you would like to follow this approach, to give you a start, consider the following code. It's not complete (some special cases marked by `...`) and it has some issues (what would happen if `middle` in the last branch would be `NULL`?), but it should give you some general idea.

```
merge_subprocedure(list, tree)
  if (list == NULL) ...
  else if (tree == NULL) ...
  else
    if (list->data <= tree->data)
      (first, middle) = merge(list->next, tree)
      head = newcell(NODE)
      head->data = list->data
      head->next = first
      return (head, middle)
    else
      head = newcell(NODE)
      head->data = tree->data
      (first, middle) = merge(list, tree->LC)
      head->next = first
      (first2, middle2) = merge(middle->next, tree->RC)
      middle->next = first2
      return (head, middle2)
```

Finally, I think that [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be much better for this question. Nevertheless, I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: dtldarek Could I also ask you something about an other algorithm?

Comment: dtldarek I did: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27661/find-an-element :)

Comment: @evinda Just ask in general, and if it is about algorithms, [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [computer science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) are a better choice.

Comment: @evinda I'm sorry I meant cs.stackexchange, not cstheory.stackexchange.

Comment: I am looking again at the algorithm... What do you mean with (first, middle) ?

Comment: @evinda It's a pair, and `(first, middle) = expr` means that `expr` should return a pair and that pair is being extracted into `first` and `middle`. You could also write `p = expr; first = p.fst; middle = p.snd;` for a pair defined as `type pair = struct { fst; snd; }`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: So what does the function merge(list->next, tree) return?

Comment: If I understand my own code (this was quite a while ago), then `merge(list, tree)` returns `(x, y)` where `x` is the first element of the output list and `y` is the element corresponding to the last element of the given tree. In other words, if on the list starting with `x` there are some elements that may need yet to be re-merged (e.g. with the other branch of the tree `RC`), then these start after `y`, i.e. at `y->next` if not null.

Comment: So with the function merge(list, tree) do we merge the list with the tree and we return the first element to the new list and the last element of the tree? :/ Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: First element of the new list and the element of the new list that corresponds to the last element of the tree.

Comment: How do we want to use the element of the new list that corresponds to the last element of the tree? :/

Comment: @evinda It's in the code, if you don't know what to do about it, why don't you use the easier two-step approach described in the first part of the post?

Comment: Could you explain me what the function tree_to_list does?

Comment: @evinda My post already explains what it does, and the code is really simple...